# Chart.js v3 - beginAtZero does nothing to my chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I read many threads on the beginAtZero parameter in Chart.js, but none of the solutions I found actually work for me.

I have a simple line chart with dates on my x axe and integers in my y axe. I can't manage to make my y axe start with 0.

```
 let atchoum = document.querySelector("#atchoum")
    let statchoum = new Chart(atchoum, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: {{ atchoumDate|raw }},
            datasets: [{
                label: "Nombre d'éternuements au support",
                data: {{ atchoumNb|raw }},
                borderColor: "blue",
                tension: 0.3,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                       y: {
                           beginAtZero: true
                       }
                    },
                    animations: {
                        y: {
                            easing: 'easeInOutElastic',
                            from: (ctx) => {
                                if (ctx.type === 'data') {
                                    if (ctx.mode === 'default' && !ctx.dropped) {
                                        ctx.dropped = true;
                                        return 0;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            }]
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your options in the dataset itself.
The options object is supposed to be on the same level as the `type` and `data` fields since the options are for the entire chart and not for a single dataset.

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 7, 9, 20, 8]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```